# Could we have a tag like „puzzles“?

Tags: discussion

I‘d wish we had a tag called „Puzzles“.

Recently someone  asked: What means inuendo. I thought this must be joke as it was clear that was a part of dim...

Comment: Do you mean like music-based challenges? There's an SE called [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music), and they have a tag for music-themed puzzles of all sorts, if you're interested.

Comment: I know this puzzle SE. My problem is there are often questions where I suppose this is a Q/A or something like a puzzle. I think this SE should indicate what sort of problem it is. How could we mark them as such?

Comment: I think it's assumed on pretty much all SE sites that OP does not know the answer to the question they ask. If it is some sort of puzzle or challenge, they should be indicated as such (and are not always on-topic, either, depending on the site).

Answer (score 2):

I also liked that question. But I think having puzzle questions wouldn't work well here within the Q/A framework. Over at Puzzling.SE they've developed a convention of using spoiler tags to hide the answers so more people can participate, but we don't have that convention established here and I think it would a very hard job to bring it about.